# Query Result Not Perfect on Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have table Like This

```
 ID | City     | Prize
_______________________
  1 | Surabaya | Notebook
  2 | Surabaya | Notebook
  3 | Surabaya | 
  4 | Bandung  | NoteBook
  5 | Bandung  | PC
  6 | Bandung  | Handphone
  7 | Bandung  |
```

I want group my table by City, Prize, and Qty Like This :

```
 ID | City     | Prize    | QTy
______________________________
  1 | Surabaya | Notebook  | 2
  2 | Bandung  | Handphone | 1
  3 | Bandung  | NoteBook  | 1
  4 | Bandung  | PC        | 1
```

I try This Query but Not Perfect this My query

```
SELECT City, prize, count( prize ) AS qty
FROM `my_table`
GROUP BY hadiah
```

Can anyone Help me for fix this Problem?

Im very Appreciated your answer.

Thanks

I Have Try query From JoeTaras

```
SELECT Kota, hadiah, count( hadiah ) AS qty
FROM unik
WHERE hadiah IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY kota, hadiah
```

And the result is still not true, The Null Value is Count too
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT City, prize, count( prize ) AS qty
FROM `my_table`
WHERE prize IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY city, prize
ORDER BY count(prize) DESC
```

Comment: I would add an order by so that it orders the qty results to.

Comment: @DalmTo: I've edited my answer with order by clause

Comment: @JoeTaras Thanks, but the Result is Still not true, the qty count the Null rows

Comment: @Uchsun: Is not true, count doeìsn't count the null rows, go here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/769f9/1/0 I've create for you a SqlFiddle example

Comment: @JoeTaras Oke Thanks for Your Answer. It Work. My Result count the Null row because my default Column is blank and not Set to NULL. After Set Null the result is true. Thanks A Lot :)

Comment: @Uchsun: Ok, have a nice day ;)